# How to hide SWT Browser or run in headless mode?

Tags: java, swt, headless-browser

I took the rendered page from the SWT Browser and exported it to an image. My problem is that I am not able to get it to export properly when the shell is not visible. How can I go about hiding the browser and have the image export properly?

I have tried setting `shell.Visible()` to false but that messes up the image export.

This is how I export the image (not sure if this is necessary to the question):

```
GC source = new GC (shell);  
Image image = new Image(display, browser.getClientArea()); 
source.copyArea(image, 0, 0);
ImageLoader io = new ImageLoader ();
io.data = new ImageData[] { image.getImageData() };
File f = new File (currentDir+"/workpng.png");
io.save (f.getAbsolutePath(), SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be impossible because the X server/Windows will throw away all rendering commands when the window isn't visible (no point in rendering what you can't see).

Also what is the client area of the browser in this case?

To make this work, you'll need to allow the shell to open be visible (i.e. not hidden by some other window). Tools like Jenkins use a plugin that starts an X session with [Xvfb](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin) or [Xvnc](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin). After setting the env variable `DISPLAY`, all UI rendering goes to these sessions.

Comment: Hmm I see. So this would also need xserver. I remember you mentioned SWTBot and that I could use that to run SWT Browser in a headless mode. Do you have any suggestions on this?

browser.getClientArea() returns a rectangle object. This is what it returns for me: `Rectangle {0, 0, 600, 400}`

Comment: Did you know that you can run an X server without attaching a monitor? And this blog post might help: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RunningEclipsePluginTestsWithSWTBotInHeadlessMode